# custom comment fields on CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, comments

I want to create few comments custom fields for my CPT and remove the default ones.

I will have just two custom fields more exactly 2 radio inputs.

Here is my code:

```
function debate_comment_fields( $fields ) {

 if( is_singular( 'debate' ) ) {

     $fields['url'] = ''; 
    $fields['author'] = ''; 
    $fields['email'] = '';


    $fields['first'] = '<p class="comment-form-first"><label for="first">' . 
                     __( 'HTML5' ) . 
                     '</label>' . 
                     '<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true).'" /></p>';


    $fields['second'] = '<p class="comment-form-second"><label for="second">' . 
                       __( 'FLASH' ) . 
                       '</label>' .
                      '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'disagree', true).'" /></p>';

    return $fields;


}
} 
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','debate_comment_fields');
```

The problem is that on my default blog posts the url, author and email fields are removed also and I'm expecting to see them there because I've added `if( is_singular( 'debate' ) ) {`

And if I submit a comment inside my CPT I get: `ERROR: please fill the required fields (name, email).`
It seems that it's still asking me for those fields.

What's wrong with my code? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Non-CPT Comments

Regarding the first issue: you're *not returning anything* if your conditional is false. To simplify your code:

```
function debate_comment_fields( $fields ) {
    // If conditional is true
    if( is_singular( 'debate' ) ) {

        // Do some stuff to $fields
        // Return $fields
        return $fields;
    }
    // If conditional is not true?
} 
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','debate_comment_fields');
```

You need to return the default `$fields` if your conditional is not true:

```
function debate_comment_fields( $fields ) {
    // If conditional is true
    if( is_singular( 'debate' ) ) {

        // Do some stuff to $fields
        // Return $fields
        return $fields;
    }
    // If conditional is not true?
    return $fields;
} 
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','debate_comment_fields');
```

This will ensure that the default fields are returned for non-CPT post comments.

### CPT Comments

The second issue you're running into is that, for your CPT comments, the comment form isn't sending name and email, which are required. There are two solutions:

1. [Disable name/email as required fields globally](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5299/3966)
2. [Filter `preprocess_comment`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/31337/3966) to allow CPT post comments to bypass the required-field check

Comment: Regarding the first issue, it's working, THANK YOU!